# how to inject bad blocks to a physical drive in Linux

Tags: linux, storage

how to inject bad blocks to a physical drive in Linux.

I have created LUN of RAID5. I need to inject bad blocks into one of the drive.

can anyone guide me, how to do

Comment: Bad block - (computer science) a block (usually one sector) that cannot reliably hold databad block - (you can try using the stone to destroy the drive)

Comment: You can use the `sg_write_long` function. More information here http://sg.danny.cz/sg/uu_index.html#support